# EventBue in Vue.js on dynamic elements $off removes for all reused components and not one

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, event-bus

I have a dynamically generated component that can be mounted multiple times on a page at the same time. For instance, if there are 10 food items returned from a feed, there are 10  components. This FoodItem component has an event bus being created on mount like so:

```
mounted() {
  EventBus.$on('SOME_EVENT', this.handleMyEventUniquely);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  EventBus.$off('SOME_EVENT', this.handleMyEventUniquely);
},
methods: {
  handleMyEventUniquely(event) {
    // this component, although mounted 10 times, will react different that the others.
  }
}
```

This works. However, if 1 of the 10 components is removed, it fires the beforeDestroy lifecycle event and removes that event bus listener for the ENTIRE app. I only need it to remove it for that INDIVIDUAL component. Is there a way to do this? Also note that I am not looking to put this in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved for it. The above code does work, it was just a scoping issue on my end. I was improperly swapping self with this.